# UIDatePicker shows incorrect date for non-Gregorian calendar

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

Here is a snippet from my code in Xcode:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSPersianCalendar];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;  
NSDate *dt = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"date is: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:dt]);    
self.datePicker.calendar = cal;
self.datePicker.date = dt;
```

When I ran the code, NSLog prints the correct date ('date is: Wednesday, Farvardin 2, 1391'). However, my datePicker is being displayed with the incorrect date: 'Dey 12, 1390'.

I am new to this stuff, but have searched extensively and could not find the reason for this behaviour. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you found a fix? it took me 2 day now trying to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: No, I used a UIPickerView and implemented the non-Gregorian date picker myself.